# Can't extract data from parsed JSON Hash in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, hash, extract

I am trying to extract elements from this API response, but I am not able to for some reason. I have the following API response body: 
`

```
[
  {
    "ID": "295699",
    "restriction": [
      {
        "restrictionTypeCode": "10001"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`
Now, I simply want to print restrictionTypeCode

```
  json_string = RestClient.get "#{$uri}", {:content_type => 'application/json'}
  hash = JSON.parse(json_string) 
  code= hash['restriction']['restrictionTypeCode']
  puts code
```

the above code errors out and it doesn't display the restrictionTypeCode

Comment: What error is raised? Which line from? Could you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: Thank you @mrzasa. I updated your code, but now I am getting Nil values in the console  $uri = "URL"
  $json_string = RestClient.get "#{$uri}", {:content_type => 'application/json'}
  $hash = JSON.parse($json_string)
  puts $hash.first&.dig(:restriction)&.first&.dig(:restrictionTypeCode)
  puts $hash.flat_map { |hsh| hsh[:restriction]&.map { |sub_hsh| sub_hsh[:restrictionTypeCode] } } . When I output the $json_string or the hash I can see the entire response. But when I output the 2 lines that you provided, I get empty 2 lines in the console for both "puts" above

Comment: it's not me, it's @SRack that helps you :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your data is returning arrays in places. Try the following:

```
data = [
  {
    "ID": "295699",
    "restriction": [
      {
        "restrictionTypeCode": "10001"
      }
    ]
  }
]

data.first[:restriction].first[:restrictionTypeCode]
# to make this safe from any nil values you may encounter, you might want to use
data.first&.dig(:restriction)&.first&.dig(:restrictionTypeCode)
# => "10001"

# or 

data.flat_map { |hsh| hsh[:restriction]&.map { |sub_hsh| sub_hsh[:restrictionTypeCode] } }
# => ["10001"]
```

To break it down a little, your top level response and that falling under the key `:restriction` both return arrays; therefore, to get the data from them you either need to access one of the items they contain (in my example using `first`) or map them (the second example).

I've added some checks for `nil` values in there: this is pretty vital when dealing with API responses as you're not in control of the data so can't be certain all the fields will be present. Rather than throw an error should you encounter data like this, you'll get `nil` returned to avoid breaking subsequent code.

Hope this helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions :)

Comment: `hash.first['restriction'].first['restrictionTypeCode']`

Comment: Also most probably symbols, not strings as keys

Comment: Thanks @mrzasa - good catch. I'll update. Much appreciated :)

Comment: How did you get on with this @DeanE?